# $G$-equivariant map between Lie group representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Say $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a $G$-equivariant map between finite dimensional $G$-representations, for some semi-simple Lie group $G$. If I know:

- $B$ decomposes into irreducibles as $B = B_1 \oplus ... \oplus B_k$
- $f(a) \in B_i$ for some $a \in A$, $f(a) \neq 0$

Must the decomposition of $A$ into irreducible $G$-reps contain a copy of $B_i$? Does the answer change depending on whether $f(a)$ is a highest weight vector for $B_i$?

Comment: Minor correction: $0 \neq f(a)\in B_i.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context, but the answer to your first question should be yes if you are thinking of complex semi-simple Lie groups. Indeed, this should be true in any setting where your representations decompose into irreducibles for purely formal reasons.

First a reduction: Schur's lemma holds in the context of Lie group representations, so every map to an irreducible $G$-rep is either zero or surjective. If $V = G\cdot a \subseteq A$ is the cyclic subrep generated by $a$, then of course $f$ defines a $G$-morphism $V \to B_i$ which is surjective (as long as $f(a) \neq 0$). From this we can see that $B_i$ is a quotient of $V$.

So your first question is equivalent to the following fundamental question: does every irrep which arises as a quotient of a $G$-representation $V$ actually arise as a subrepresentation? Equivalently, does every sub-representation have a complement? This is equivalent to asking for *complete reducibility*, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_representation).

For (edit: forgot to emphasize semisimple) Lie algebras, the answer is affirmative (this the fundamental result of Weyl) and the same basic result holds for compact Lie groups (one can construct complements by some kind of Reynolds averaging argument, or equivalently, one can normalize the representation to be a unitary representation and then construct complements via orthogonality). Since every *semisimple complex Lie group* has a compact real form, the result holds in that context too.

Comment: The last paragraph seems a little off to me. Weyl's theorem holds for **semisimple** Lie algebras specifically and if it holds for a Lie algebra it works for any of its Lie groups as well so we have no need to appeal to compact real forms (except as a way to prove Weyl's theorem itself)

Comment: How does the argument go for passing from Lie algebras to an arbitrary (maybe connected?) Lie groups for it? For the simply connected G you have an equivalence, and then the ones which descend to some other G' are the subcategory which are invariant for the action of the fundamental group? How do you know every splitting of a representation which descends also descends?

Comment: My instinct is to try to think of things in terms of twisting to the compact real form of the group, which is why I emphasized it in the last sentence.

Comment: Simply using the fact that invariant subspaces for the Lie algebra representation are invariant subspaces for the Lie group representation (if the latter exists). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604850/a-subspace-is-invariant-by-the-lie-group-if-it-is-invariant-by-the-lie-algebra), for example. Note the representation descends to representations on these subspaces simply by restriction.